# activiti REST API get/post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activiti

REST API get/post request question
I am trying to work with the activiti API with tomcat and using postman to test my get/post request, but I was not able to get request the data, like show all the tasks, complete a task and other.

Here is what I did

```
1. Put version 5.13 acitiviti-explorer.war and activiti-rest.war inside webapp in tomcat 7.0.42 
2. Startup tomcat 
3. go to http://localhost:8080/acitiviti-explorer
4. log in as username: kermit, pw: kermit
5. Tasks -> create a couple Tasks like 
    1. Task1
    2. Task2 
    3. Task3

6. Use chrome Postman - REST Client
7. setup postman 
    - Basic Auth: username: kermit, pw: kermit 
    - Header: Content-Type, Value: application/json

8. Input 
    URL: http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/tasks
    select: GET

result: 
{
"errorMessage": "Tasks must be filtered with 'assignee', 'owner', 'involved', 'candidate'        or 'candidate-group'",
"statusCode": 400
}
```

---

```
From the User guild under REST API
List of tasks: GET runtime/tasks
URL: http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks
select: GET

result: 
{
    "data": [
{
"id": "101",
"url": "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks/101",
"owner": null,
"assignee": "gonzo",
"delegationState": null,
"name": "enim Ut ut fugiat adipisicing in",
"description": "Duis do Ut anim do cupidatat aute dolore nisi et reprehenderit laborum ad      Excepteur dolore",
"createTime": "2013-10-15T19:42:17.352+0000",
"dueDate": null,
"priority": 50,
"suspended": false,
"taskDefinitionKey": null,
"parentTaskId": null,
"parentTaskUrl": null,
"executionId": null,
"executionUrl": null,
"processInstanceId": null,
"processInstanceUrl": null,
"processDefinitionId": null,
"processDefinitionUrl": null,
"variables": []
},
{
"id": "103",
"url": "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks/103",
"owner": null,
"assignee": null,
"delegationState": null,
"name": "irure do adipisicing eiusmod veniam amet",
"description": "Ut minim Lorem elit officia laborum dolore consequat pariatur enim     adipisicing adipisicing quis amet aliquip",
"createTime": "2013-10-15T19:42:17.358+0000",
"dueDate": null,
"priority": 50,
"suspended": false,
"taskDefinitionKey": null,
"parentTaskId": null,
"parentTaskUrl": null,
"executionId": null,
"executionUrl": null,
"processInstanceId": null,
"processInstanceUrl": null,
"processDefinitionId": null,
"processDefinitionUrl": null,
"variables": []
},
..................
],
"total": 100,
"start": 0,
"sort": "id",
"order": "asc",
"size": 10
}

I have also tried a couple others as well but it's too long to post it all up
but ideally I would like get back all the information about 
Task1, Task2 and Task3 using the API. Also I notice that there are total of 100 Tasks 
from  Get URL: http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks in Postman 
where as only total of 3 tasks that we created, from 
http://localhost:8080/activiti-explorer/#database/ACT_RU_TASK or under tasks in the browser
```

We have also tried to start a Vacation Request process and claimed the tasks and was not able to get those information from the rest API

I was wondering if we have used the wrong URL or other processes that we have missed

At the end we want to use Ruby on rail as a front end for the activiti

Please let me know if additional information is needed
thank you so much

Comment: I have used Activiti 5.12  and to get list of tasks i had to send any of the following query parameter `assignee` or `candidate` or `candidate-group`. Try passing any of these parameter and see if you get the result.

Comment: I am using Activiti 5.13 since they have alot of improvements but anyhow. I also tried to use this URL http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/tasks?assignee=kermit but result was the same I get back a list of kermit's default tasks in latin like above, that are tasks that I just created in activiti-explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call wrong URL:

Call

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks
select: GET
```

I have tested it and it works fine. I get list of all tasks.

Activiti 5.13 also provides a unit-test that calls that URL without params (`TaskCollectionResourceTest.testGetTasks:155`)

Comment: If you look at the second part, I have tried that as well. But it gave me back a list of default tasks, total of 100, that are not in my activiti-explorer and all the description came up with latin words. So far I am just trying to play around with their default setting, and trying to add tasks in the activiti-explorer and trying to use get to the list of tasks that I just created

Comment: Since I was not able to get the tasks that I just created from activiti-explorer through the url. I don't think unit-test would help at this point. I was thinking it might be something to do with the default h2 database, in which I have also followed [link](http://bpmn20inaction.blogspot.com/2013/02/activiti-in-action-updates-part-1.html) that address the issue with the database for the pervious version; however, that was not the case

Comment: I believe that It is something to do with the default H2 database that's connect to the activiti-explorer and activiti-ReST being not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been struggling with a similar problem, and the last answer helped me a lot to be able to make use of the rest API bevause I likewise was using the wrong query URLs. I also have postman installed and although I can see various tasks in my activiti-explorer inbox, the following query...

From the User guild under REST API
List of tasks: GET runtime/tasks

```
URL: http://myserver:8088/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks
```

select: GET

results in:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "total": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "sort": "id",
    "order": "asc",
    "size": 0
}
```

...as if there were no tasks there. Maybe I got something wrong, but as far as I gleaned from the manual, it is not necessary that some process be running in the backgound to enable me to gather them with the rest query (I use the port number 8088 in the stead of 8080).